# DML File 'enum' class Error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, enums, dml

I am writing on a DML file the next source of code:

```
enum Permission;
```

It generate a file `.java` where it will generate this error:

```
excepting "class", found 'enum'
```

I also tried to code other sample of my DML file function as well as:

```
enum Permission{
   OWNER,
   ROOT,
   READ,
   WRITE,
   READWRITE
}
```

And it has the same error.

Comment: which java version are you using? I think enums have been introduced with Java 1.6 or Java 7. Earlier java versions cannot deal with enum types.

Comment: I am sorry to disagree but "enums" must be used on my project work and I am using Java 8. But steel like I said it is a part of the version.

Comment: Java 8 should be ok - I said something about **earlier** versions ^^